# Java RMI new object for each call and queue

Tags: java, rmi, remote-access

There is any way of set java **rmiregistry** to return a new instance of registered object **for each calling**, or only creating a **factory pattern** at server side?

Furthermore, is there a way to do a **queue** in java Rmi, if there a "overflow" of clients calling server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the factory a remote object, put it into the registry, and have the client call it whenever it wants a new object.

There is no such thing as an overflow of RMI clients except at the TCP level. There already is such a queue in TCP, namely the listen backlog queue.

Comment: Another way if you are using JNDI at both client and server is to register a Reference with an appopriate object factory, which will execute at the client side.